# Getting compilation error "activity_main" can not be resolved or is not a filed

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

I am trying to instrument my Android application with some SDK that enables me to test my mobile application on device. I needed to create a MainActivity class in my app where I have the following method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

But I get the following compilation errors:

> "activity_main can not be resolved or is not a field"

I have seen postings in this regards and the provided solution has been:

> Remove "import android.R;"
>
> Add "import Application.package_name.R;

I have done this as follow:

import com.MyMobileApp.R

Where "com.MyMobileApp" is the package name where R.java resides but the error persists even after a re-build\clean the project.

If I provide the name of the application to import statement is can not be resolved and I do not think its even necessary since I am referencing a package in the same application.

Also, I checked R.java class that is a generated file and seems that can not be modified since Eclipse gives me the warning that the file can not be edited. So in R.java file under layout I do not see any "activity_main" filed in there. I have the following in R.java class under layout:

```
public static final class layout {
    public static final int cycleslistheader=0x7f030000;
    public static final int feedback=0x7f030001;
    public static final int login=0x7f030002;
    public static final int master=0x7f030003;
    public static final int overlay=0x7f030004;
    public static final int problem=0x7f030005;
    public static final int testcycle=0x7f030006;
    public static final int testcycles=0x7f030007;
    public static final int user=0x7f030008;
    public static final int userlistheader=0x7f030009;
```

So has anyone applied any solution other than the one explained above.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a layout file called activity_main.xml to inflate into your ContentView

Comment: there are a bunch of layouts, but none of them is called `activity_main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple example of a layout, we will call it activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/hello_world"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Go into eclipse, right click on your project -> New -> Android XML file. Name it activity_main.xml and paste the above into it. Save it and you are good to go.

Android dev page for layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

In your onCreate() method, you are calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); This is telling Android that you want the layout for your activity to be the one described in xml in your activity_main.xml layout file (in the layout folder in your res folder). If you don't have one there, it won't be able to inflate the layout and you will get your error. This will give you a very simple view, you can change it as needed for your project. Note there are tons of layouts and views, and you can even make your own custom ones to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It resolved my problem and I am all set. I will review the provided document as well.

Cheers!